# One click upload setting not able to save

Tags: 7, commerce, wysiwyg, views

I want upload file enable to upload image from my system for that i have installed ONE CLICK UPLOAD plugin for drupal and using Ck editor. now i have to change preference setting for upload button but when i changed toolbar buttons its not saving my changes and i am not able to add that upload button to my editor. please guide if anybody has any solution. my setting path for drupal ch editor is:: module > ck editor > edit/config > **Editor appearance**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use drupal image field for this. You can use add multiple image with drupal core cck image or you can install contrib module multiple image widget. You can be use to display on page or using views can be display.

Comment: Can you provide some related link or demo. i am kinda new here so

Comment: You have configured content type for this go for manage fields and add new field image configure image field as your requirement. Then go for manage display where you can configure your display. simple. If you want upload multiple image at a time add module [multiwidget](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget).